# .htaccess. deny root, allow specific subfolder. Possible?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

How can I deny access to http://sub.mydomain.com/, but allow for (completely) http://sub.mydomain.com/test (or http://sub.mydomain.com/test/)

There is a magento back-end behind http://sub.mydomain.com/test/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

.htaccess directives [apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#what), so you should disallow access in your DocumentRoot,

http://sub.mydomain.com/.htaccess:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

And override that in any specific subdirectories you would like to allow access to,

http://sub.mydomain.com/test/.htaccess:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: This is an untested assumption but you just need that second `.htaccess` in any subdirectory that is supposed to be web accessible

Comment: Doesn't work for me - adding .htaccess with "Allow from all" in a subdir still requires a password for it.

Comment: However, adding "Satisfy Any" in addition to the above did fix it.

Answer (score 9):

How about a [.htaccess](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess) at the root directory, with the following lines?

```
RewriteEngine On
# check if request is for subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.mydomain.com$ [NC]
# check if  'test' isnt part of request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/?(.*)$ [NC]
# if subdomain and no 'test' part, redirect to main domain...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

So if the '/test/' section is present, no redirect takes place...

Comment: Looks pretty interesting. I have to admit, i'm not realy familiar with mod_rewrite. So I have absolutely no clue what [NC] and [R,L] stands for...

Comment: NC means case insensitive, R = redirect, L = last (stop applying rules from htaccess after this)

Answer (score 1):

Try create .htaccess file in sub.mydomain.com for deny, and in sub.mydomain.com/test for allow.

Or you can redirect from http://sub.mydomain.com/ to deny subdir.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread, but I've been struceling with exactly this scenario for several days and finally got it to work, thus I thought I'd share my solution for further reference.

As of Apache version 2.4 (I guess), it's possible to use directive `<RequireAll>` and `<RequireAny>`.
This can be used to allow access to specific subfolders.

My solution for .htaccess (inspired from this site: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/apache-authorization/):

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/test/.*" PUBLICACCESS
# Use for multiple subfolders:
# SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/(?:test|test2|test3|test4)/.*" PUBLICACCESS
<RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
        # Public access
        Require env PUBLICACCESS
        Require all granted
    </RequireAll>
    <RequireAll>
        # Require user and password
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Secured"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/example.com/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
</RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a cpanel powered server which will add .htaccess entries like the following:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
# Section managed by cPanel: Password Protected Directories     -cp:ppd
# - Do not edit this section of the htaccess file!              -cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile "/home/****/.htpasswds/sites/****/passwd"
Require valid-user
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
# End section managed by cPanel: Password Protected Directories -cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
```

I wanted to allow access to a specific subfolder, and the solution was creating an .htaccess file within that subfolder and placing the following inside:

```
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have protected your DocumentRoot by Auth, then you can allow your Subfolder by follow:

http://sub.mydomain.com/test/.htaccess:

```
require all granted
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```