# I want to put a 403 forbidden in one of my directory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block one of my website directory by 403 error message but not its sub folders or sub directory. I want the .htaccess coding for this. I have tried the coding , it blocks those sub folders also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess. deny root, allow specific subfolder. Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649794/htaccess-deny-root-allow-specific-subfolder-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules in the htaccess file in the folder you want to block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ - [L,F]
```