# How can I override my parent dir .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a folder 'includes' on my apache server where I keep some php and other automation documents. The folder contains the .htaccess file below.

```
<Limit POST PUT>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
Options -Indexes
```

This restricts some access to the files in this folder and its subfolders. And works fine.

How can I have custom read access settings in one of the subfolders?

- Example 1: One folder `includes/exampleone` I want to disallow Get
  requests.
- Example 2: A second folder `includes/exampletwo` I want to allow all,
  for dev/test purposes.

Is it as simple as putting a new htaccess file in the subfolders? I tried that for example 2 and used the below

```
<Limit POST PUT GET>
  order deny,allow
  deny from none
  allow from all
</Limit>
Options -Indexes
```

But got a page missing error navigating to the directory or a .php file within it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess. deny root, allow specific subfolder. Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649794/htaccess-deny-root-allow-specific-subfolder-possible)

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen that one. Although I did search. Still though, I did try that, yet the page in example two is still not found.

Comment: To be clear, I tried as above and also `Order allow,deny
Allow from all` from your link and got the same result.

Comment: I made a test with exactly your code (+ limit GET in the first .htaccess) and that's works fine. So maybe it's an error inside the .php or about apache configuration

Comment: OK thanks, I'll have another play and see how I go. At least now I know it should be possible.