# Htaccess - Disallow going backwards?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

is there a way to disallow to go backwards to another directory?
E.g.: The URL is http://www.example.com/subdirectory/

If there is a HTML file which links to the the URL "/file.txt" it should not leave the subdirectory. The slash has to be ignored. Are there some Rewrite Rules in htaccess to do this? The subdirectory should be handled like a root directory.

Comment: Change `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: You really should stop thinking in terms of the 80th. Today URLs usually should not match to physical folders in the servers file system any more. Access to files should nearly _always_ be routed through scripts.

Comment: Do you access to Apache config?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here. I believe it is what you are looking for:

[.htaccess. deny root, allow specific subfolder. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649794/htaccess-deny-root-allow-specific-subfolder-possible)