# How to allow to view a file in (/../)subfolder using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How to allow to view a file in (/../)subfolder using .htaccess ?

Folder structure:

```
root/
root/.htaccess
root/public
root/public/.htaccess
root/public/index.php
root/public/css
root/public/js
```

root/.htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 Options -MultiViews
<FilesMatch  ".*">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#i tried to add here, public directory permission, but it does not work
#with DirectoryMatch i am getting the error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
#without DirectoryMatch i am getting the error You don't have permission to access /type705b/public/index.php on this server.
<DirectoryMatch "/public.*">
 Allow from All
</DirectoryMatch>
```

root/public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
Options -MultiViews
#wrong according comments <FilesMatch "public.*" >
  Allow from all
#</FilesMatch>
#the rest of htaccess below
```

If i try to view root/public/index.php, i am getting the error :`Forbidden You don't have permission to access /root/public/index.php on this server.`

After the corrections, i am getting `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`
The error log for the code above says  `xxx/htdocs/root/.htaccess: <DirectoryMatch not allowed here`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess. deny root, allow specific subfolder. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649794/htaccess-deny-root-allow-specific-subfolder-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you have `<Files ~ "^public.*" >`, that's wrong.

The correct one should be `<Files ~ ".*" >` because you already has the `RewriteBase /public/`

---

`<Files ~ "^public.*" >` will allow only files that match `public.*` but as a file name, not as a path nor dir.

Comment: thank you, it still does not work, now i am getting the error `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: Have a look at your error log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: [Wed May 24 17:51:19.948912 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4892:tid 1232] [client ::1:53133] xxx/root/.htaccess: <DirectoryMatch not allowed here

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649794/htaccess-deny-root-allow-specific-subfolder-possible

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have any rewrite rule in `public/.htaccess`, you don't really need anything in `public/.htaccess` other than this line:

```
Allow from all
```

Moreover `Files` directive is used for matching file names only so it can never match a file path that includes directories also.

Comment: Similarly you can just have `Deny from all` in your site root .htaccess

Comment: thank you, but it does not work. Adding allow fall to public, gives `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: Why are you adding `allow fall` ? I wrote `Allow from all`

Comment: I added allow from all to code and quesrion, only comments has an error. Thanks for noticing and for replying.

Answer (score 0):

The working combination  to allow to view a file in (/../)subfolder using .htaccess :

Folder structure:

```
root/
root/.htaccess
root/public
root/public/.htaccess
root/public/index.php
root/public/css
root/public/js
```

root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
Deny from all
```

root/public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

Options -MultiViews
Allow from all
#the rest of code
```

Using `<File > <FileMatch > <Directory > <DirectoryMatch >` was giving the errors.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote in my answer. You don't even need `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` lines in both .htaccess